# PHP: preg_replace with arrays will not replace whitespace with hyphen

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

This is doing my head in.  This code comes from a much more complex function but the fundamental issue I'm having stems from here.

Assuming:

```
$string = 'new page!';
```

Why does:

```
$string = preg_replace(array('/\s/', '/\W/'), array('_', ''), $string);
```

correctly produce a result of:

```
'new_page'
```

but this:

```
$string = preg_replace(array('/\s/', '/\W/'), array('-', ''), $string);
```

will return:

```
'newpage'
```

I've tried escaping, but nothing seems to work.  It's like the hyphen is just ignored completely.

Even more strange:

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s/', '-', $string);
```

will work correctly and return 'new-page', but I'd like to replace whitespace and non-word characters at the same time.

Anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace(array('/\s/', '/\W/'), array('-', ''), $string);
```

On the first step,  spaces are replaced with `-` and on the second step both the replaced hyphen and `!` are stripped off (replaced with empty string) because `-` is also a non-word character. Note that the  output of first replacement was feded as input to the second replacement.

```
$string = preg_replace(array('/\s/', '/\W/'), array('_', ''), $string);
```

Produces `new_page` because at first spaces are replaced with `_` and on the second replacement all the non-word characters must be replaced with an empty string. Since `_` is not a non-word character, it won't get removed. `!` is a non-word character , so it got removed.

You could do like this to get your desired output.

```
$string = 'new page!';
echo preg_replace(array('/\s/', '/[^-\w]/'), array('-', ''), $string);
```

Output:

```
new-page
```

**OR**

change the order.

```
$string = 'new page!';
echo preg_replace(array('/[^\s\w]/', '/\s/'), array('', '-'), $string);
```

**Output:**

```
new-page
```

Comment: Of course!  Obviously I've been staring at this thing too long.  Reversing the search array and then getting the word character regex to ignore spaces has fixed it!

Answer (score 1):

Because after you replace whitespace with a hyphen, `\W` replaces that non-word character. I would personally use a callback function to do this. You can tweak this to your needs...

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('~(\s)|\W~', 
     function($m) {
        return $m[1] ? '-' : '';
     }, $str);
```